# can a perceptron be used for regression?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In machine learning, the [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is an algorithm for supervised learning of binary classifiers. A binary classifier is a function which can decide whether or not an input, represented by a vector of numbers, belongs to some specific class.

on wiki page, the problems section includes regression without more explanation.

[image]

can a perceptron used for regression?

Answer (score 3):

The deep feedforward neural networks used for regression are nothing but multilayer perceptron architectures.

[image: Perceptron]

Originally, perceptrons were used as binary classifiers i.e to classify binary labels ( 0 or 1 ). But, if no non-linear activation function is applied to the dot product of the features and weights, then it is simply a linear regressor.

If the linear function is $f(x) = x$ and $N$ is the number of features then,

$\Large y = \sum_{i=0}^N x_i w_i$

or using vector notation,

$\Large y = \vec{x}.\vec{w} ...(1)$

For multiple regression, we use the below equation with mean-squared error loss function to optimize the $\beta$ parameters,

$\Large y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 ... \beta_n X_n$

Let ,

$\Large 
\vec{W} = [ \beta_1 \ \beta_2 \ \beta_3 \ ... \ \beta_n ] \\
\vec{X} = [ X_1 \ X_2 \ X_3 \ ... \ X_n ]
$

Where $N$ is the number of features, $\vec{X}$ is the feature vector and $\vec{W}$ is the weights vector. Then,

$\Large y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 ... \beta_n X_n = \beta_0 + \vec{W}.\vec{X} ...(2) $

Where, $\beta_0$ is also called as the bias coefficient in Artificial Neural Networks. You can relate equations 1 and 2 and understand the concept.

> Hence, $\Large y = \vec{x}.\vec{w} + bias $ generally represents a hyperplane
>   which is used in linear regression.

Answer (score 2):

Yes a perceptron (one fully connected unit) can be used for regression. It will just be a linear regressor. If you use no activation function you get a regressor and if you put a sigmoid activation you get a classifier.

Actually, with neural networks, classification is a special case of regression where we "regress" the probability of belonging to a given class. That's why the loss function for classification is called "logistic regression".